# Pushing to Github Repo from Eclipse, how to hide sensitive data, but make repo public?

Tags: java, git, github

I am wondering how I can push to my Github repo (which I need to be public so I can showcase to employers), without showing sensitive info. I am using Eclipse/Java.

I have made a project which runs tests with Selenium webdriver in Chrome, I don't want people to be able to see the login information in my code, for obvious reasons.

The stuff online about Git/Github is a bit of a minefield for a beginner like me and I am finding it hard to understand.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use a .gitignore file. It contains all the files that should not be published to your git repo. See the doc for gitignore here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy reply, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split all (hardcoded) configuration data into a separate file, for example `Config.java` or `application.xml` or some format you like.

Create a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in your project directory, listing all the files / folders that should be ignored, for example the configuration file mentioned above, and some other generated file, compile output, <del>jar file,</del> etc.

If you have accidently added some sensitive data that exists in your Git history, use `git filter-branch` to remove those file from history.